# How to retrieve a specific element with from xml with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to read through an xml feed I'm getting, but I can't access the specific elements. I'm using python, and the python documentation is really unclear about what I should use.

Here is the feed:

```
<title>More eagle</title>
<summary>http://www.181.fm/winamp.plsstation=181eagle&amp;style=&amp;description=The%20Eagle%20(Classic ...</summary> 
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail account_id=example@gmail.com&amp;message_id=12995390f36c310b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html" />
<modified>2010-07-02T22:13:51Z</modified>
<issued>2010-07-02T22:13:51Z</issued>
<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1340194246143783179 </id>
```

And here is my current function:

```
def parse_xml(feed):
    feedxml = minidom.parseString(feed)
    name = feedxml.getElementsByTagName('name')
    subject = feedxml.getElementsByTagName('title')
    contents = feedxml.getElementsByTagName('summary')
    return name + "\n" + subject + "\n" + contents
```

Comment: To clarify, I need to get the text between the element tags. Right now I'm getting  the following:

<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x14b7c10>
[<DOM Element: name at 0x14dd210>]
[<DOM Element: title at 0x14d8760>, <DOM Element: title at 0x14d8c38>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getElementsByTagName()
```

returns a list of elements. So if you want the first (or only) one, you need to use `getElementsByTagName('name')[0]`.

But this is an element object, not the text enclosed by it (which I presume you're interested in).

So you probably need to do something like this:

```
nametag = feedxml.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
nametag.normalize()
name = nametag.firstChild.data
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of an element you have to do something like this:

```
  def getElementText(node, tagName):
    for node in node.getElementsByTagName(tagName):
      result = ""  # handle empty elements
      for tnode in node.childNodes:
        if tnode.nodeType == tnode.TEXT_NODE:
          result = tnode.data
    return result

  def parse_xml(feed):
    feedxml = minidom.parseString(feed)
    name = getElementText(feedxml,'name')
    subject = getElementText(feedxml,'title')
    contents = getElementText(feedxml,'summary')
    return name + "\n" + subject + "\n" + contents
```